# Increase value of variable by parameter of function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to create a timer in JavaScript but I don't know how to assign value of parameter of function to global variable. I can do this without using parameters but I want to reduce number of lines in my source code.

Here's my code:

```js
const elemHoursIncreaseBtn = document.querySelector('.hours__increase__btn');
const elemHoursCount = document.querySelector('.hours__count');
let hours = 0;

function increaseCount(unit, number, elem){
    if(unit<number){
        unit++;
        if(String(unit).length<2){
            elem.textContent = "0" + unit;
        }else{
            elem.textContent = unit;
        }
    }else{
        unit=0;
        elem.textContent = "0" + unit;
    }
}

elemHoursIncreaseBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    increaseCount(hours, 23, elemHoursCount);
   });
```

```css
.flex__center{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.timer__container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.increase__pick, .decrease__pick, .hours__count, .minutes__count, .seconds__count{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Timer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/timer.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="timer__container">
        <div class="hours__picker">
            <button class="increase__pick hours__increase__btn">/\</button>
            <p class="hours__count">00</p>
            <button class="decrease__pick hours__decrease__btn">\/</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../js/timer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How exactly does using a parameter reduce lines of code *(in this example)*?

Comment: It's not all of code. There will be 6 buttons which they will doing exacly the same but for other element so reference to one function but with other parameters is better than writing almost the same code six times.

Comment: But will they all be updating the same global `hours` element?

Comment: If you want to update the global variable, you can't pass it as a parameter. `unit` in the function is a local variable, and changing it doesn't change the value of the passed global variable. Just refer `hours` directly in the function.

Comment: No, two buttons (increase, decrease) will be updating hours, next two minutes and next two seconds. It's timer application as you have on your phone but I dont want to insert value manually on keyboard but by buttons.

Comment: If `increaseCount` is one of those button click handlers, `hours` is not updated.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid it because then I still have to code 6 functions. One for increase hours next one for decrease hours etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the actual values in a map, pass in the key for the map that you want to adjust, and reference it.

```js
const elemHoursIncreaseBtn = document.querySelector('.hours__increase__btn');
const elemHoursCount = document.querySelector('.hours__count');
const units = {
  hours: 0,
  minutes: 0,
  seconds: 0
};

function increaseCount(unitType, number, elem){
    if(units[unitType]<number){
        units[unitType]++;
        if(String(units[unitType]).length<2){
            elem.textContent = "0" + units[unitType];
        }else{
            elem.textContent = unit;
        }
    }else{
        units[unitType]=0;
        elem.textContent = "0" + unit;
    }
}

elemHoursIncreaseBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    increaseCount('hours', 23, elemHoursCount);
   });
```

```css
.flex__center{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.timer__container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.increase__pick, .decrease__pick, .hours__count, .minutes__count, .seconds__count{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Timer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/timer.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="timer__container">
        <div class="hours__picker">
            <button class="increase__pick hours__increase__btn">/\</button>
            <p class="hours__count">00</p>
            <button class="decrease__pick hours__decrease__btn">\/</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../js/timer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but I have two questions:
1. Why is the class type of const? Shouldn't be var or let?
2. Why did you you use ' ' to refer to hours in parameter?

Comment: 1) `units` is typed as `const` as the object doesn't change.  The values the keys point to in the object change.  2) You pass in `'hours'` because you are providing the string key that relates to the object. `units.hours === units['hours']`